# W3 schools HTML include files

Tags: html, include

I am using W3 Schools include script.  It works for all HTML files that do not exist inside a folder.
This is how the code looks:

```
<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>
```

When I try to use the same include script for a sub directory, the W3 Schools include does not work. I have tried a couple of different ways to try to get it to work, for example:

```
<div w3-include-html="../content.html"></div>
```

or

```
<div w3-include-html="../../content.html"></div>
```

Does anyone know how to get this work?  Here's [the link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) to the w3schools example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use full directory of the file you want to include? If the folder has the same root as the HTML you are running, you don't need to add `../` just put:

```
<div w3-include-html="folder/content.html"></div>`
```

Then check if there is an error with your code.

Comment: Ok cool I just tried, I put the <div w3-include-html="content .html"></div> in the same directory as the nested Html files, still nothing.

I also removed  ../

Comment: So I did there's no error in the code I check l 4 times

Comment: So this is what I did

Comment: <div w3-include-html="../acquisition/content.html"></div>
 and I also tried 
  <div w3-include-html="acquisition/content.html"></div>

Comment: I've tried to use it lately and I can't use it without hosting it with apache. After using localhost it works fine. And don't forget to include the w3.js file. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: @ Yvanget
where you able to use it in a nested folder?

Comment: Yes. I've tried it and it worked properly. Can you edit your post up there with your whole code and file name. Are you using localhost to run it?